# How to use AWS SNS to send sms usibng ExAws

Tags: elixir, amazon-sns

I am trying to send an SMS using AWS SNS service through [ExAws](https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws), [ExAws.SNS](https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws_sns)

I don't find proper documentation for it.

I tried the following code but it is throwing error.

`%{name: "message", data_type: :string, value: {:string, "Hello..."}} |> ExAws.SNS.publish(%{phone_number: "+911010101010"})`

Error

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for %{data_type: :string, name: "message", value: {:string, "Hello..."}}. This protocol is implemented for: Atom, BitString, Date, DateTime, Decimal, Ecto.Date, Ecto.DateTime, Ecto.Time, Float, Geo.GeometryCollection, Geo.LineString, Geo.MultiLineString, Geo.MultiPoint, Geo.MultiPolygon, Geo.Point, Geo.PointM, Geo.PointZ, Geo.PointZM, Geo.Polygon, Integer, List, NaiveDateTime, Postgrex.Copy, Postgrex.Query, Postgrex.Stream, Time, URI, Version, Version.Requirement
    (elixir) /private/tmp/elixir-20180130-42559-1d5vx7w/elixir-1.6.1/lib/elixir/lib/string/chars.ex:3: String.Chars.impl_for!/1
    (elixir) /private/tmp/elixir-20180130-42559-1d5vx7w/elixir-1.6.1/lib/elixir/lib/string/chars.ex:22: String.Chars.to_string/1
    (elixir) lib/uri.ex:109: URI.encode_kv_pair/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1366: anonymous fn/4 in Enum.map_join/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1263: :lists.foldl/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1915: Enum.map_join/3
    (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/operation/query.ex:24: ExAws.Operation.ExAws.Operation.Query.perform/2
```

I am sure that the way I am preparing the query is not proper.

Comment: _What_ error is it throwing?

Comment: Updated with the error.

Comment: Try adding `|> Poison.encode!()` before calling `publish`. The message needs to be a JSON encoded binary, not a map.

Comment: @Dogbert That is not possible as I am using touple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently [`ExAws.SNS.publish/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_sns/ExAws.SNS.html#publish/2) expects two parameters: mandatory `message` of type `binary()`  and optional `opts` which is a keyword list (including e. g. `:phone_number`.)

As per a [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html), the message should be a JSON-encoded string. That said, you should likely pass the message as is to `ExAws.SNS.html#publish/2` and the options should be a `Keyword`, not a `Map`:

```
ExAws.SNS.publish("Hello...", [phone_number: "+911010101010"])
```

Comment: Now getting an error from AWS.

```Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: +911010101010 is not valid to publish to```

Comment: This is _AWS_ rejecting the phone number, Elixir did whatever it could to it’s best.

Comment: It is an issue with the configured region.

Comment: Not all regions support sns. You can set the region like this: `ExAws.SNS.publish("This is a test from Elixir", phone_number: "+15551112222")  |> ExAws.request(region: "us-east-1")`